# Node.js MondgoDB during routing

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have some problems trying to manage the backend for administration.
Here is my route (in /routes folder):

```js
//getseriestv.js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Camis = require('./models');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/App');
router.get('/seriestv', function(req, res, next) {
 
 var camis = Camis.find({}).lean().exec(function(err, results){
 //I want to deliver it to jade from mongo DB problems :S
 res.render('getseriestv', { camis: camis } );

 });
});


module.exports = router;
```

And here, the Jade file:

```html
extends layout

block content
  h1= title
  -for camiseta in camisetas
    .li = camiseta.titulo
      .panel
        li= camiseta.descripcion
```

I don t really know why has crashed, the Output is thisone:

```html
Not Found

404

Error: Not Found
    at C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\app.js:42:13
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
    at C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
    at next (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\serve-static\index.js:120:7)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
    at SendStream.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at SendStream.error (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\send\index.js:245:17)
    at SendStream.onStatError (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\send\index.js:356:12)
    at next (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\send\index.js:630:16)
    at onstat (C:\Users\reinoso\Desktop\server\myapp\node_modules\send\index.js:619:14)
    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
```

That's all, I am not capable to solve it since I have been like two whole days trying to fix it (but nothing...).

Comment: Post app.js or at least the relevant part (line 42)

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 issues with your code.

```
res.render('getseriestv', { camis: camis } );
```

should probably be

`res.render('getseriestv', { camis: results } );`

as results is what contains database records from the call to find(...)

and inside your jade template

```
for camiseta in camisetas
```

should be

```
for camiseta in camis
```

as camis is what is defined as the JSON key in the render(...) call

Comment: None of this issues are related to the problem

Comment: Probably not. His stack trace suggests that the problem is in app.js but the code he posted still has problems as I highlighted in my answer. May be I shouldn't have posted it as an answer. A comment would have been appropriate I guess.